# List of all shared folders

Tags: command-line, filesystem, shared-folders

Is there possible to list all shared folders (with their physical locations) from command line?

Answer (score 9):

go to list folder

> /var/lib/samba/usershares

check the path

Comment: Under this path (`/var/lib/samba/usershares`) only some of my shared folders are available. In other machine there is other folders shown under my machine such as: My Printers, `print$` and `IPC$` which are not listed in the pass in your answer!

Answer (score 8):

Use this command: `smbclient -L localhost`. A sample of its output is as follow:

```
Enter username's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (host-name server (Samba, Ubuntu))
hp1320          Printer   Hewlett-Packard hp LaserJet 1320 series
HP-LaserJet-1200 Printer   HP LaserJet 1200
Public          Disk      
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
                     host-name server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            HOST-NAME
```

Comment: I get this error: `Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)`

Comment: Are you trying this on the machine that has the share setup? Else change it to the IP address of the server you are trying to read.

Comment: @Lokesh I think Tobias' coment was meant to be addressed to you. I'd also mention that this specific error usually means that nobody is listening on 139 and 445 port *(samba should be listening on at least one of them)*. You can check if it's true with `ss -an | grep -P "\b(139|445)\b"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
gvfs-mount -l
```

GVFS is the virtual filesystem for the Gnome desktop that allows access to shared drives via SMB, FTP, WebDav, and SFTP. Accessed shares are mounted under `~/.gvfs/`, you can see them there as well.

The command above lists all attached external drives, and network shares, e.g.:

```
$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): 1.5 TB Hard Disk
[snip]
Mount(0): public on fileserver -> smb://fileserver/public/
  Type: GDaemonMount
Mount(1): SFTP for bert on server.example.com -> sftp://bert@server.example.com/
  Type: GDaemonMount
Mount(2): WebDAV as bert on server.example.com -> davs://bert@server.example.com/dav
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

If you add the option `-i` you get even more information.

Comment: Worth mentioning, the command is deprecated in preference of `gio mount -l`

Answer (score 5):

For samba shares we have a set of utilities that come with the [samba](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/samba) [image: Install samba] suite:

- **smbtree**

  > smbtree is a smb browser program in text mode. It is similar to the "Network Neighborhood" found on Windows computers. It prints a tree with all the known domains, the servers in those domains and the shares on the servers. <sup>[Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/smbtree.1.html)</sup>
- **smbstatus**

  > smbstatus is a very simple program to list the current Samba connections. <sup>[Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/smbstatus.1.html)</sup>

  By invoking the following a list of shares will be displayed:

  ```
  smbstatus --shares
  ```

See also: [Manpage of samba](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/samba.7.html)

Comment: Non of `smbtree` and `smbstatus` commands list my shared folders!

Comment: @PHPLearner: try with `sudo smbstatus --shares`

Comment: This is the result for `sudo smbstatus --shares`: 
`Service      pid     machine       Connected at` (nothing in the list).

Answer (score 2):

If you browse your own machine in the Network section of Nautilus, you should see all the shares.

Comment: In Nautilus, the is a "Browse Netwrok" Item in the sidebar. Inside it, there is only one item: "Windows Network" and inside it there is only one item: "WORKGROUP". If I double click WORKGROUP it asks me for user name and password and if I enter my user name and password for my Ubuntu, it does not accept it! Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run the following command:

```
smbtree
```

Comment: I tested this command, but it only shows: `WORKGROUP
 \\                 host-name server (Samba, Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 0):

At least two ways to do this:

##### 1. mount

```bash
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1959288k,nr_inodes=489822,mode=755)
...
# etc, etc
```

With no options, `mount` will list all mounted file systems. Two options are available:

- `-l` : includes labels
- `-t <type> : filters the output by filesystem <type>; e.g.` cifs`

See `man mount` for details. An example from my system:

```bash
$ mount -l -t cifs
//NetgearNAS-3/backup on /mnt/NetgearNAS/backup type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.246,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
//SynologyNAS-1/backups on /mnt/SynologyNAS/backups type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.102,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,user=seamus)
```

##### 2. findmnt

From `man findmnt`:

> findmnt  will  list  all  mounted  filesystems  or  search  for  a  filesystem.   The  findmnt  command  is able to search in /etc/fstab, /etc/mtab or /proc/self/mountinfo.  If device or mountpoint is not given, all filesystems are shown.

With no options, `findmnt` provides a neat listing of all mounted filesystems in *tree* format:

```bash
$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE                 FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1              ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
├─/sys                                sysfs                  sysfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security              securityfs             securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                    tmpfs                  tmpfs      ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755

...

# etc, etc
```

`findmnt` has an extensive set of filtering and formatting options, making it well-suited for use in scripts where the output must be parsed - see `man findmnt` for details. In this case, if we wish to restrict the output to shares (as in the smb/cifs/nfs sense), the `-t` option is handy:

```bash
$ findmnt -t cifs,nfs4
TARGET                     SOURCE                           FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share SynologyNAS-1:/volume1/rpi_share nfs4   rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,se
/mnt/NetgearNAS-3/backup   //NetgearNAS-3/backup            cifs   rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.16
/mnt/SynologyNAS/backups   //SynologyNAS-1/backups          cifs   rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.
```

Comment: @andrew.46: That's fine... I agree that closing the other question was the right thing to do. Just so you know, my thinking was, "Well, if they allow duplicate questions here, why not duplicate answers?"