# How can I configure password based access and list all shared directories?

Tags: samba

I'm using Ubuntu/Samba and I seek for an explanation how to:

- put password protection access to computer, not on single directories
- list all directories that I share, and not search them manually

I always put directories to permit guests, because when I don't do that when I try access it says invalid permissions. I can't even use my root/user password combination to access.

Comment: For listing of shared directories see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/198501/list-of-all-shared-folders

Comment: OK, but I still can't see location on my local drive of the folders that I share, only their names (following the commands on that page) `smbtree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not being too lazy, I found what I needed. These are probably basic things for advanced users:

- I couldn't access protected shares with my root username/password because ***I didn't add that user*** to samba system (it seems that it doesn't take automatically ubuntu users, and its user/pass system exists by its own which is a good thing). ***To add a user*** just use `smbpasswd -a [USERNAME]` and then type the new password.
- For ***listing all local shares*** and their paths just access `/var/lib/samba/usershares` folder and there you have all configuration files for every single shared directory. Inside the file you have fields **path** (with the path to your local directory) and **guest_ok** (y/n type to permit guests) which you can edit manually.

I will not lock this topic yet, waiting for improvements from other users (if there's anyone who will read this). I just wrote this answer to help some other lost noob like me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can type `testparm` to make sure your syntax is correct in smb.conf ... plus it'll show you all the shares you have in there.