# How to find/locate real directory by share name?

Tags: shared-folders

I have a shared directory sharedfolder, but cannot find it after OS restarted.
I have found:

```
/var/lib/samba/usershares$ cat sharedfolder
#VERSION 2
path=/tmp/sharedfolder
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:F
guest_ok=y
sharename=sharedfolder
```

But where is this /tmp?
When I go to /tmp then I do not see this folder.
What I do incorrect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all shared folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198501/list-of-all-shared-folders)

Comment: I have tried this way: not found